# Jwt authentication in php

Tags: php, mysql, jwt, backend

On an app for user generated content that has a mobile and web version, if the app users two versions of the same backend php code, one version for the mobile and another version for the web which has jwt security implemented on (addressing of endpoints will vary based on the directory each backend codebase is in and the web's backened has a /jwt/ directory).

How would this affect user uploads when done from web or mobile, how would web and mobile both successfully fetch a user uploaded file uploaded either via web or mobile?

Will this create a problem in display on both mobile and web?

If the above question is yes, how would you go about solving it?

Answer (score 0):

JWT- The JSON Web Signature is a cryptographic mechanism designed to secure data with a digital signature unique to the contents of the token in such a way that we are able to determine whether the data of the token has been tampered with or not.

Advantage of JWT-

1. API keys are just random strings, while JWTs contain information and metadata that can describe user identity, authorization data and the validity of the token within a time frame or domain.
2. JWTs do not require a centralized issuing or revoking authority.
3. OAUTH2 compatible.
4. JWT data can be inspected.
5. JWTs have expiration controls.

e.g.- eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE0MTY5MjkxMDksImp0aSI6ImFhN2Y4ZDBhOTVjIiwic2NvcGVzIjpbInJlcG8iLCJwdWJsaWNfcmVwbyJdfQ.XCEwpBGvOLma4TCoh36FU7XhUbcskygS81HE1uHLf0E

Libraries-
composer require firebase/php-jwt:dev-master
composer require zendframework/zend-config:~2.3
composer require zendframework/zend-http:~2.3

```
Code-
<?php
```

/*

- Code here...
  */

  /*

  - Extract the key, which is coming from the config file.
  - 
  - Best suggestion is the key to be a binary string and
  - store it in encoded in a config file.
  - 
  - Can be generated with base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(64));
  - 
  - keep it secure! You'll need the exact key to verify the
  - token later.
    */
    $secretKey = base64_decode($config->get('jwtKey'));

  /*

  - Encode the array to a JWT string.
  - Second parameter is the key to encode the token.
  - 
  - The output string can be validated at http://jwt.io/
    */
    $jwt = JWT::encode(
    $data,      //Data to be encoded in the JWT
    $secretKey, // The signing key
    'HS512'     // Algorithm used to sign the token, see https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-jose-json-web-algorithms-40#section-3
    );

  $unencodedArray = ['jwt' => $jwt];
  echo json_encode($unencodedArray);

Comment: Did you actually read and understand the question? I don't see how your answer is related in any way to the question.